# Rails: Query a model from a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have Post and SubCategory models that have a belongs_to and has_many relationship respectively.

In the Show view of Post, in addition to showing an individual Post, I need to run the index action of the SubCategory controller to show the current SubCategory and all of it's Post in a left Nav area.

What's the best way to go about this?

EDIT I was already utilizing Application Controller so I think this is the best route to go especially if I want to do the same thing in other views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :load_application_wide_varibales

  def load_application_wide_varibales

  def get_subcategory_and_post
    @sub_category = SubCategory.all
  end
end

class PostController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_subcategory_and_post, only: [:show]

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end

class SubCategoryController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :get_subcategory_and_post
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
  helper_method :current_user
  end
end
```

Posts Show View

```
<% @sub_category.each do |subcat| %>
<div class="leftnav">
<h1 class="name"><%= subcat.name %></h1>
<% subcat.posts.each do |post| %>
<ul>
<li><%= link_to (post.name), post %></li>
</ul><% end %> 
</div>  

<% end %>
<div class="rightContent">
<p id="notice">
  <%= notice %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= post.content %>
</p>

</div>
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category
  belongs_to :users
  validates :name, :content, :sub_category_id, :presence => true
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :sub_category_id
  after_save    :expire_post_all_cache
  after_destroy :expire_post_all_cache

def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |post|
      csv << post.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end

def self.all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('Post.all') { all }
end

def expire_post_all_cache
  Rails.cache.delete('Post.all')
 end
end
```

SubCategory model:

```
class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :posts
  validates :name, :category_id, :presence => true
end
```

Working Posts Show view:

```
<div class="leftnav">
<h1 class="name"><%= @post.sub_category.name %></h1>
<% @post.sub_category.posts.each do |post|%> 
<ul> 
<li><%= link_to (post.name), post %></li> 
    </ul><% end %>  
    </div> 

<div class="rightContent"> 
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> 

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>  
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>  
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make a partial (something like _subcategory_list) that takes a subcategories collection and renders them. Then your Post view can call `render(partial: 'subcategory/subcategory_list', locals: { subcategories: @post.subcategories })` and your SubCategory list view can do the same except pass in its @subcategories value.

Comment: Hey Dan, since I might want to extend this out to other views do you think it may make more sense to configure this in Application Controller as noted below?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I didn't realize you were loading every subcategory regardless of whether a page was loaded. However, I would still use a partial for the subcategory list, or include it in the layout file so that you don't have to repeat the code in each view.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to your_controller_action_url and return
```

This will render another controllers action. However, this is contrary to how logic should be separated in controllers and typically considered to be a bad practice.

Your best bet would be to abstract the logic in the SubCategory controller to `ApplicationController` and then both the post and sub-category controllers can use it.

Here's an example with fake methods:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_subcategory_and_post
    # Logic here
  end
end

class PostController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_subcategory_and_post, only: [:show]

  def show
    # Logic here
  end
end

class SubCategoryController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_subcategory_and_post
end
```

Comment: I like your direction since I was already utilizing Application Controller. See my edit above. In posts/show I'm getting this error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Ok, I get that <% @sub_category.each do |subcat| %> is not needed here. I need to grab the sub_category of the current post (but post.sub_category.name doesn't work) and then call sub_category.posts.

Comment: Can you post your models? Assuming that the current post is an instance variable, you might be able to reference it in your get_subcategory_and_post method. If not, you likely have access to your params and you could do a look-up that way.

Comment: Ok, I can access the SubCategory name with `<%= @post.sub_category.name %>` but I can't iterate over it and find all the posts with: `<% @post.sub_category.name.each do |subcat| %>`

Comment: Ok, I got it to work but let me know what you think of the code, see edited post at top.

Comment: If it works, that's good. It doesn't look like you need the method in ApplicationController or any of the before filters though. Your show view doesn't use the instance variable set in it. You could remove it.